# Node.js Express: Redirect or render on post

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, routes

I have a post route that looks something like this:

```
router.post('/:name/book', function(req, res){
    Booking.create(myNewBooking, function(err, booking){
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        //What am I supposed to do here? I usually do:
        req.app.locals.booking = booking;
        res.render('booking_success.jade');
    });
});
```

The problem: If the user refresh after doing this post request, they send the same data again. I don't want that to be possible. What is the best way to prevent this? I thought of this:

```
router.post('/:name/book', function(req, res){
    Booking.create(myNewBooking, function(err, booking){
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        res.redirect('/booking-success');
    });
});

router.get('/booking-success', function(req, res){
    res.render('booking_success.jade');
});
```

Is this the way to go? Or are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Yup, this is a common pattern. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these options are done regularly.  The reason to choose the redirect over the render is purely based on what you want to happen after the post.

If this is an API called by some external script (either Javascript via Ajax or any outside agent), then you should just render an acceptable (and probably small) response, often a simple piece of JSON.

If this is a form submission from a browser web page and you want the URL in the browser to end up on something that matches the rendered content, then a redirect makes great sense.

If this is a form submission, either option will clear the form from the browser and prevent a simple repost of the same data.

Answer (score 1):

Though you can use both of the methods but looking at the above case you don't need to do `res.redirect()` and then `res.render()` you can directly do `res.render()` from the first route itself.

`res.redirect()` will be useful if you have routes which you can hit directly or via a redirect so that you don't have implement the same logic again in two places.